# How to add element with jquery append and set text value increase

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
   var total = 1;
     if (total<10) {
        total = total + 1;
        text = '<p>text '+ total +'</p>';
        $("#box").append(text);
     }
});
```

View:

```
<button id="btn">button</button>

<div id="box"></div>
```

Result:

```
<p>text 2</p>
<p>text 2</p>
```

How to make value increase every click button? 
Like this:

```
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text 2</p>
<p>text 3</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define `total` out the of the `click scope` (as `global`) you will be succeed what you've tried.

```
var total = 1;

$("#btn").click(function() {

     if (total<10) {
        total = total + 1;
        text = '<p>text '+ total +'</p>';

        $("#box").append(text);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Optimized Code:

```
var total = 0;
$("#btn").click(function() {
     if (total<10) {
        $("#box").append('<p>text '+ total++ +'</p>');
     }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qe0h459d/